# CMS LGPL branding

Tags: content-management-system, lgpl

I am considering extending a content management system which is licensed under the LGPL.  My question is if I can rebrand the CMS.  I'm only going to be charging for my customizations and implementation.  I'm just wondering if I can brand it as PhilCMS (as an example).

I'm just not really sure as I don't see anything regarding branding in the LGPL.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always with questions related to licenses, you should first read the license thoroughly (sounds like you've done that), and then if you still have questions, consult a technically-competent lawyer.  Understanding this stuff is their job.

That said, the LGPL allows modifications to the source.  Changing the branding is, so far as the license is concerned, just another source change.  Make sure to preserve attribution as necessary.